# What is the probability A or B occurs?

Tags: probability

A has a probability of 30% B has a probability of 50% .. 
A and B are independent events.
What is the probability A or B occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability),
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).
$$
Then use the definition of the independent events.

Comment: @Saurabh That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that two events A and B are independent if and only if 
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B).$$
Hence the probability A or B occurs is given by
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B).$$

Comment: thnxx nice ....